# Is there a significance to the unit number 366117891 in the Marvel A New Hope comic adaptation?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, comics, a-new-hope

In the 1977 Marvel *[Star Wars #4](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_4:_In_Battle_with_Darth_Vader)* comic, which was part of an adaptation of *A New Hope*, there is an additional scene after the trash compactor stops where Luke tells C-3PO the unit number so that he can open the hatch.

[image]

I find it interesting that attention is given to this detail that is not in the final version of the film and that Luke reads the whole number.

This makes me wonder, is there significance to the number 366117891 the same way there was to Leía being in cell block 1138 (a reference to Lucas' earlier movie *THX 1138*)?

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cf48taiXIAE8-zr.jpg

Comment: Yes, the scene is from the original script, but it never made in the final movie. There are some of those in this early comic series. To me, it looks like Lucas has just hit some random number keys of his typewriter; first one with his left hand, then twice with his right hand, twice left, three times right, and one more left.

Comment: fwiw - the hatch number stated in the film is different "three-two-six-three-eight-two-seven"

Answer (score 1):

**Not according to Wookieepedia or TheForce.net.**

It's unlikely that 366117891 is significant. I Googled "366117891" and it only came up with results for the trash compactor. No pages mentioned that it could be an easter egg.

It's unlikely that the number 366117891 is important.

Comment: Neither of those (fan-written) websites are a definitive accounting of the Star Wars universe. The absence of information on those pages is merely indicative of their ignorance on the subject

Comment: @Valorum If any page was to have any knowledge of _anything_ Star Wars, it would be Wookiepedia.

Comment: The problem with using wookiepeedia as a source of info for a 'negative' answer is that it's not definitive or even especially comprehensive. They have hundreds of updates a week, correcting mistakes and creating articles.

Comment: @Valorum And it is almost _never_ wrong. If you can give me 5 situations in which Wookiepedia was wrong, I would applaud you.

Comment: This is a list of [85 commonly misspelled words](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookieepedia:List_of_common_misspellings) on Wookieepedia;

Comment: The R2-D2 page alone has had [dozens of errors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-D2?action=history) on it over the years, mostly people adding in fan-info without justification. A fan-written wiki is only as good as the info available to fans. Lucas may have had a very significant reason to use that number (a phone number, perhaps) but wookieepedia would be unware if he's not spoken about it. **All we can surmise from its absence from wookieepedia is that *wookiepedia editors don't know about it***

Comment: @Valorum I'm not looking for commonly misspelled words.

Comment: Did you look at the history page for R2-D2? This is my favourite... http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-D2?diff=6909289&oldid=6909282

Comment: @Valorum,Wow. I didn't know Padme was a fan of cheese doodles.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t find a significance for 366117891, but I found a reference for 3263827. According to this website (https://wegotthiscovered.com/movies/mark-hamill-sneak-real-phone-number-star-wars-hope/), 326-3827 plus a Hollywood area code might have yielded Mark Hamill’s (Luke Skywalker) phone number (when he was living in Hollywood).